# How to bind properties of a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming

I want to bind UIView frame with its Corner radius so
Corner radius of the view stays 1/2 of view's frame width. 
if the view frame changes it triggers its corner radius value

I hope for a solution that can be Generalized for class properties beyond UIView

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = view.bounds.width * 0.5
```

Also two methods are called whenever bounds change:

`viewWillLayoutSubviews()` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` , you can change radius value there.

I would solve this with extension:

```
extension UIView {
  func changeFrameAndCorner(frame: CGRect) {
    self.frame = frame
    self.layer.cornerRadius = view.bounds.width * 0.5
}
```

Comment: He said specifically that if the frame changes he wants the cornerRadius to remain 50% of the width. This provides a solution to the initial frame width but not an increasing one

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite setFrame method

```
 - (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
   super.frame = frame;
   self.layer.cornerRadius = ///
}
```

If it's not your view you can use KVC and observe when views frame changes (if needed can provide code, but internet is full of it...).And than when it changes update your corner radius.

Otherwise you need to use some libraries for Reactive programing(Reactive Cocoa, RxSwift, Bond etc).

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom subclass of UIView and override setFrame as @Volodymyr suggested. That wouldn't work for system classes however.

You could also probably implement the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method in your view controller and adjust your view's corner radius based on any changes to the view's frame.

Finally, you should be able to subscribe to key value notifications on the view's frame.